# Is it possible to display the HTML provided by the admin panel app on-site?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I've built a site where I can create new posts (essays) by the admin panel. The output is visible to users. But when I place some HTML as content in the form it doesn't render itself on the page.

example:

[image]

Output on the page (with marked unrendered HTML):

[image]

I would like to know how to fix it and also, how to name the topic I want to know ( I couldn't find anything related to my problem, probably because I don't know how to express it).

Additionally, I just start to wonder if there is one more problem nested inside. How to link **CSS** from the static folder having this HTML mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django offer the autoescape template in the builtins tags

```
{% autoescape off %}
{{ myhtml }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

But your logic seems wrong, you don't need to create a new page with the doctype, just create a base template and use the block content tag to insert your article.

In your base template replace the description and title of your page by variables that will be populated by the article data.

You need to learn the basic of Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ trust me you won't regret it !

Comment: Hi, the auto escape template is what I was looking for! The idea that you mentioned is implemented in my blueprint but in a different fashion - with the base template. The problem I had was that I wanted to be able to add the content of the article by the Administrator's panel, and not through the IDE editor. When writing through the administrator's panel, I need to be able to generate headers and insert pictures. Thanks to this, I can fill the database with articles without interference with the page code itself.

Comment: About security risks: because the text will be coded only by the administrator and not users, there is no risk of a hacker attack. The only thing I don't know is if HTML is the only option to format the text that is the contents of the form. Is there any other way to format that?